# How to generate code first migration script from a specific migration?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a production and a development database. Now I want to generate a sql script based on a specific migration. When I enter the line to generate the script I get this error:

`'201608121243147_AutomaticMigration' is not a valid migration. Explicit migrations must be used for both source and target when scripting the upgrade between them.`

The command I use is as follows:

`Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:201608121243147_AutomaticMigration -TargetMigration:201608281101542_AutomaticMigration`

When I execute the command `get-migrations` I can see those two migrations are in the list. The target migration is also my latest migration, but when I omit this parameter I get the same exception.

What am i doing wrong? What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: I'm betting auto migrations lack the metadata to do the compare needed to script out the changes, thus the error. You could roll back your models then add a baseline starting point (add-migration MyInitial -IgnoreChanges). Now  restore your model changes and add another migration.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semicolon after `SourceMigration` and after `TargetMigration`:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration 201608121243147_AutomaticMigration -TargetMigration 201608281101542_AutomaticMigration
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Update-DataBase -Script -SourceMigration:"Version1" -TargetMIgration:"Version2"
```

Regards
Abdul