# Entity framework CodeFirst Sql Script Generation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity framework code first. I want to create Sql script for a particular Db Migration file not from starting. 
For Example: I have a table with 10 columns that I have created in my previous db migration. Now I have added the new column to the table. I want to create Sql script for this newly added migration file only.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: EF Version? Here is the answer for 6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190738/how-to-generate-code-first-migration-script-from-a-specific-migration

Comment: Steve Greene thank you very much your solution worked fine....

Comment: No problem. I would delete this question. It will remove your negative rep. Not sure why it got down votes with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Package Manager Console and simply do the following.

First, you need to create a new Migration by using:

```
Add-Migration "Name of Migration"
```

And then follow that with a command as follows.

```
Update-Database
```

This will then generate a new Migration and then push it to your database table.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is the method to apply migration to database connected to project. I want to generate a Sql script file for a particular migration. For example : Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0  this command is used to generate Script from scratch. Right from first migration

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a script that contain the difference from your previous migration.

Below command can be used to generate a script which contain the difference.

script-migration -from NameofthePreviousMigration -to NameoftheLatestMigration 
-Context DBContextName

The file generated from this command will include details that is there in your last migration.